# Override magento 2 template

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I have magento 2.0 C.E. And I want to override a few core template files. But, I do not have anything inside **app/design/frontend/magento/** and my luma theme is installed somewhere in the **vendor/** directory. I have not created any custom theme also. Please, let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a basic example.

Assume, if you want to override customer log-in form.

The original file path is from core.

```
\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\login.phtml
```

Assume you need to do some customization. then copy the files to your theme, in this example take LUMA theme.

```
\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Customer\templates\form\login.phtml
```

Then do necessary changes.

Comment: I do not have custom theme

Comment: Fine then go with default/luma theme

Comment: Can I override the template into my module?

Comment: Yes you can, bets way is by layout. please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120838/in-magento-2-how-to-override-phtml-or-layout-core-files

Comment: its not working for my case. using magenot 2.1.2